# How to disable the download option from electron-pdf-window

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron, electron-packager, pdfviewer

I'm building a django **electronjs** app with PDF viewer using the following **js** script and it's working fine, but my concern is if I can disable or remove the download option from the PDF viewer. If yes, then how can I do that?

```
const { app } = require('electron')
const PDFWindow = require('electron-pdf-window')

app.on('ready', () => {
  const win = new PDFWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  win.loadURL('http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf')
})
```

If this can be done, I will be grateful.

Comment: What is the point? The file was already downloaded to the user's machine, if the user can see it.

Comment: if he can bypass it, then its ok, but by default i need download option shown in the window should be disable.

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/session#event-will-download